# Why i keep getting bootloader error whentrying to dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu

So i'm using HP 280 G3 MT. I try to dual boot with Windows 10 and Linux. I have tried to do this with Linux Mint before, and i get `Unable to install GRUB` fatal error. When i restarted my PC, i get this:
[image]

I can't boot to my windows nor Linux. I try to change Linux Mint with Lubuntu, and hoping for better luck but, it still the same. On installation i got:

[image]

I try to enable Legacy mode
[image]

And try to reinstall lubuntu but nothing happened. Anyone know about why this happenned and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the Windows installation type? BIOS/MBR? BIOS/GPT? EFI/GPT? In a dual-boot situation, your Linux installation will need to match the Windows installation. It may also be a good idea to disable Fast Boot as that will ensure that Windows interferes with Linux's ability to correctly use some hardware when "rebooting" from Windows to Linux.

Comment: I'd also suggest you provide release details; the grub shown in your picture is not used by a supported release of Lubuntu (*possibly it's from your Linux Mint system and wasn't replaced*), but currently I have no idea what version of `calamares` (Lubuntu's installer) you're using, which can be useful in suggesting things to try (possible answers).  Currently there are ~4 *supported* versions of `calamares` available by selecting the ISO you use; some releases have more than a single choice, but you've not said what you're actually trying to install.